# Adding UITableViewCell programmatically to UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell programmatically and wish to add it to a UITableView of UITableViewController created in IB. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method add your custom cell like this -

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DashboardCell";

DashboardTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[DashboardTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

If cell contains image,text,etc then add like this -

```
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[apdelobj.array1_25 objectAtIndex:myInt]];

cell.titleLabel.text = dashboardList.mistohMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDataSource`'s delegate method `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)t cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` is just for that, no matter how cell was created, programmatically or in IB. Just return your created cell from this method. Don't forget to populate created cell with your data.

So you have provide `UITableViewDataSource` methods. Except mentioned above, this delegate has one more required method, `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. Everything else is not necessary, but often useful. Consult `UITableViewDataSource` protocol [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).